# Syncfusion MVC Grid only reads data from OData source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datagrid, syncfusion

In my app, ASP.NET MVC 4, EntityFramework and Syncfusion MVC controls i have problem with MVC Grid. 
I created OData source with Web API:

```
public class DriversController : ODataController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: odata/Drivers
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Driver> GetDrivers()
    {
        return db.Drivers;
    }
...
}
```

And this works, tested with Postman. Get data and modify it in DB.
But my grid:

```
@model dynamic

@(Html.EJ().Grid<object>("DriversGrid")
    .Datasource("http://localhost:26168/odata/Drivers")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Field("Id").HeaderText("ID").IsIdentity(true).IsPrimaryKey(true).AllowFiltering(false).Add();
        col.Field("Name").HeaderText("Nazwa").Add();
        col.Field("DriverId").HeaderText("ID pastylki").Add();
    })
    .AllowFiltering()
    .FilterSettings(d => d.FilterType(FilterType.Menu))
    .AllowSorting()
    .ClientSideEvents(events =>
    {
        events.EndAdd("onEndAdd");
       // events.Load("onLoad");
    })
    .EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding().AllowDeleting().AllowEditing(); })
            .ToolbarSettings(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.ShowToolbar().ToolbarItems(items =>
                {
                    items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Add);
                    items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Edit);
                    items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Delete);
                    items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Update);
                    items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Cancel);
                });
            })
)

<script>
    function onEndAdd(sender, args) {
        var gridObj = $("#DriversGrid").ejGrid("instance");
        gridObj.refreshContent();
    };
</script>
```

only reads data from controller, actions on grid only calls `public IQueryable<Driver> GetDrivers()`. No other actions on the controller are not called. Grid viually edits, deletes and insert data but not call odata source to store this. 
What  i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please check the browser network tab whether any `ajax` request is initiated on editing? and check for script error in browser`s console.

Comment: No requests, but i konow wat was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should change data source from

```
.Datasource("http://localhost:26168/odata/Drivers")
```

to

```
.Datasource(d => d.URL("http://localhost:26168/odata/Drivers"))
```

This works fine.